# Remove duplicate elements from list when there are many duplicate elements are present

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to remove a duplicate element from a list, it is not able to remove it ("1"), can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong

```
lst=[1,2,3,4,1,1,1,5,6,7,1,2]
    for i in lst:
        print(i)
        if i==1:
           lst.remove(i)
```

expected output -

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7,2]
```

actual output -

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2]
```

Comment: **Don't remove elements while iterating over it**

Comment: use `sets` to remove duplicates. So `list(set(lst))` will return only unique elements in `lst`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Also, see: [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists/7961390)

Comment: Just noticed that the title and the code are not related at all. See the duplicate target, it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

**Ex.**

```
lst=[1,2,3,4,1,1,1,5,6,7,1,2]
new_list = [x for x in lst if x != 1]
print(new_list)
```

**O/P:**

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2]
```

**OR**

Remove all duplicate element from list, use `set`

**Ex.**

```
lst=[1,2,3,4,1,1,1,5,6,7,1,2]
print(list(set(lst)))
```

**O/P:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```